# Use Powershell to comment out a 'codeblock' in a text file?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to comment out some code in a massive amount of files

The files all contain something along the lines of:

```
    stage(&apos;inrichting&apos;){
        steps{
              build job: &apos;SOMENAME&apos;, parameters: param
              build job: &apos;SOMEOTHERNAME&apos;, parameters: param
              echo &apos;TEXT&apos;
        }
    }
```

The things within the `steps{ }` is variable, but always exists out of 0..N 'echo' and 0..N 'build job'

I need an output like:

```
    //stage(&apos;inrichting&apos;){
    //   steps{
    //        build job: &apos;SOMENAME&apos;, parameters: param
    //        build job: &apos;SOMEOTHERNAME&apos;, parameters: param
    //        echo &apos;TEXT&apos;
    //  }
    //}
```

Is there any good way to do this with PowerShell? I tried some stuff with pattern.replace but didn't get very far.

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs' -Filter config.xml -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.fullname };
foreach ($item in $list) {
...
}
```

Comment: are you trying to comment out anything which contains a 'steps' block? the entire file? anything with those variables in it?

Comment: also if it's the steps block, can you assume it will always be the same height (lines) or at least always have the same number of braces?

Comment: there's multiple stages, I only want to comment the `stage(&apos;inrichting&apos;){` stage. So only the steps block within this stage. We can assume the same number of brackets, the amount of lines varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, as you're trying to find that whole section, and then add comment markers to all lines in it. I'd probably write an ad-hoc parser with `switch -regex` if your structure allows for it (counting braces may make things more robust, but is also a bit harder to get right for all cases). If the code is regular enough you can perhaps reduce it to the following:

```
stage(&apos;inrichting&apos;){
    steps{
        ... some amount of lines that don't contain braces
    }
}
```

and we can then check for occurrence of the two fixed lines at the start and eventually two lines with closing braces:

```
 foreach ($file in $list) {
    # lines of the file
    $lines = Get-Content $file
    # line numbers to comment out
    $linesToComment = @()
    # line number of the current block to comment
    $currentStart = -1
    # the number of closing braces on single lines we've encountered for the current block
    $closingBraces = 0

    for ($l = 0; $l -le $lines.Count; $l++) {
        switch -regex ($lines[$l]) {
            '^\s*stage\(&apos;inrichting&apos;\)\{' {
                # found the first line we're looking for
                $currentStart = $l
            }
            '^\s*steps\{' {
                # found the second line, it may not belong to the same block, so reset if needed
                if ($l -ne $currentStart + 1) { $currentStart = -1 }
            }
            '^\s*}' {
                # only count braces if we're at the correct point
                if ($currentStart -ne -1) { $closingBraces++ }
                if ($closingBraces -eq 2) {
                # we've reached the end, add the range to the lines to comment out
                $linesToComment += $currentStart..$l
                $currentStart = -1
                $closingBraces = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $commentedLines = 0..($lines.Count-1) | % {
      if ($linesToComment -contains $_) {
        '//' + $lines[$_]
      } else {
        $lines[$_]
      }
    } | Set-Content $file

 }
```

Untested, but the general idea might work.

Update: fixed and tested

Comment: Thanks a lot, took a bit of editing out some minor flaws with the code. but it worked!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the flaws, but writing code right on SO is always fraight with problems ;). Parsing this way isn't pretty, but under certain constraints it can work well enough and is much easier to get right than "proper" approaches. It's still a hack job for every specific case, though.